# recommend paper on application of group theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, applications

Application field can vary from biology\biochemistry, to computer science\coding theory, the more unexpected a connection to a field, the better. And paper preferably should be not very large one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom Fiore and his coauthors have used group theory to study various pieces of music.  You might enjoy the article "Musical actions of dihedral groups ( http://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/~tmfiore/1/CransFioreSatyendra.pdf ), or take a look at Tom's music page: http://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/~tmfiore/1/music.html

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~maurer/CSI5v93DA/Group.pdf) is a paper about applications of group theory to symmetric gates.

Answer (score 1):

See [Polya's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387964134) for an application of Burnside's lemma to chemistry.

Answer (score 1):

There are many applications of group theory to chemistry, in particular to fullerenes. If you do a "google search" with the strings: +chemistry +"group theory" or +"group theory" +fullerenes you will find many papers that deal with these topics.